# NSFetchedResultsChangeType should be NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate instead of NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

I am using Magical Record to do core data operations. In the table view controller, I setup NSFetchResultsController like this:

```
self.fetchedResultsController = [Activity MR_fetchAllGroupedBy:nil withPredicate:predicateForSmart sortedBy:@"activityScore" ascending:NO delegate:self];
```

I also wrote delegate method for NSFetchResultsController in controller.

Now when I use

```
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {
        if (activitiesWithThisID.count > 0) {
            Activity *activityToUpdate = [[activitiesWithThisID firstObject] MR_inContext:localContext];
            // Detailed update here
            activityToUpdate.someProperty = ...;
...
        }
    } completion:^(BOOL contextDidSave, NSError *error) {
```

to update data, the method

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
```

is fired. However, `NSFetchedResultsChangeType` is always `NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete`, I expect it should be `NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate`. When I use `[activityToUpdate deleteEntity]`, still `NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete` is fired but it is right.

Answer (score 0):

Bug fixed. I use `NSPredict` to find data then update entry. However, previously this find operation is in another `NSManagedObjectContext`. However, there is a problem with `NSFetchedResultsController`. The bug ends up being that during in memory evaluation of the predicate (to see if the newly inserted object belongs to the controller), the predicate ends up doing a pointer comparison. Since there are two managed object contexts, the pointer comparison will fail. So the controller ends up thinking that the new object is not part of the result set.

So just put everything in the same 'NSManagedObjectContext' and it should work.